# Subprocess commands that need each other, special trouble with "cd"

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, cd

I want a program that, with given arguments, I'm using optpatse, changes the working directory and executes some file.

I have tried with:

```
subprocess.check_call(['ls'], cwd="/home")
```

and this works. But if I do:

```
subprocess.call("cd", shell=True)
subprocess.call("ls", shell=True)
```

This doesn't work, the `"ls"` shows me where the current python file is working. I understand that both commands get executed correctly, but I need the second one be executed at the directory from the first command.

```
def followpath(path):

    subprocess.call("cd", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("ls", shell=True)

#The real thing I want to execute is:

    subprocess.call("cd", shell=True)
    subprocess.call(["cd", path])
    subprocess.call(["python3", somepyfile])
```

I expect also that, after running the script in the terminal, the working directory changes to the path and the somepyfile is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` creates a child process, your `cd` will therefore change the CWD of the *child* process (which then immediately exits). You want `os.chdir(path)` to change the CWD of your program.

Comment: And how can I work with the child process? And now yes, it changes the dir, but when the program finishes returns to the old dir of the script file

Comment: Also worth noting that it's not possible to change the working directory of the shell running the script. When the script completes, the shell/terminal you ran it from will be where it started.

Comment: ok, so I could open a new shell in the wanted path and execute the file with the os module?

Comment: @AjapolloTrukatila Changing the directory of the Python interpreter itself thus changes the directory of programs it starts -- so `os.chdir()` puts the Python interpreter in the right directory; and then when you start an external program, it's in that directory right off the bat.

Comment: @AndrewGelnar, please note, in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the section *"Answer Well-Asked Questions"*, and the bullet point therein regarding questions which "have been asked and answered many times before".